# Bundler old version uninstall trouble

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle, bundler

I try to uninstall old version of bundler, but in list of gems he's remains. After installing newest version of bundler, I get errors about I use old version of bundler for rails 4.0.2.

```
stasik@stasik-TWH:~/Seti$ gem list bundler
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
bundler (1.2.3)
stasik@stasik-TWH:~/Seti$ gem uninstall bundler
INFO:  gem "bundler" is not installed
stasik@stasik-TWH:~/Seti$ rails new app1
      create  
      create  README.rdoc
      ...
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
         run  bundle install
/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1: No such file or directory -- /usr/share/rubygems-integration/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/bin/bundle (LoadError)
```

Comment: Are you using something like RVM with shared or global gemsets? It might be from a different gemset. Otherwise you shouldn't worry about having an old version of bundler installed, you'll automatically use the newest version.

Comment: Oh thanks, I fix it using `sudo apt-get remove bundler`. Also I re install rails. And that's works.